# Rails render html from mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want render html from mysql2. What is wrong?
Here is Error code

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Stores#index
Showing /home/rok/Development/Pan/app/views/admin/stores/index.html.erb
```

where line #15 raised:

```
undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x007f627f0cf808>
Extracted source (around line #15):

    13   <% @store_list.each do |stores| %>
    14      <tr>
    15         <th><%= stores.name %> </th>
    16         <td><%= stores.address %></td>
    17         <th><%= stores.phone %></th>
    18      </tr>
```

Here is my view code
index.html.erb

```
  <% @store_list.each do |stores| %>
  <tr>
     <th><%= stores.name %> </th>
     <td><%= stores.address %></td>
     <th><%= stores.phone %></th>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my controller code

```
    class Admin::StoresController < ApplicationController
      $client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "rok", :password => "xxxxxx@", :database => "Pan_development")

      def index
        @store_list = $client.query('select * from stores')
      end

    end
```

my routes

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :stores
end
```

rake routes

```
admin_stores GET    /admin/stores(.:format)           admin/stores#index
             POST   /admin/stores(.:format)           admin/stores#create
new_admin_store GET    /admin/stores/new(.:format)       admin/stores#new
edit_admin_store GET    /admin/stores/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/stores#edit
admin_store GET    /admin/stores/:id(.:format)       admin/stores#show
             PATCH  /admin/stores/:id(.:format)       admin/stores#update
             PUT    /admin/stores/:id(.:format)       admin/stores#update
             DELETE /admin/stores/:id(.:format)       admin/stores#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

```
undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x007f627f0cf808>
```

Looking at your error message, `stores` is a Hash. You can't access the hash key/value using `.` operator.

#### Solution

You should be able to access the `name` of the store by using: `stores[:name]` or `stores['name]`. See the [documentation](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) on how to retrieve the value of a key in a Hash.

So, this should fix your problem:

```
<% @store_list.each do |stores| %>
    <tr>
      <th><%= stores['name'] %> </th>
      <td><%= stores['address'] %></td>
      <th><%= stores['phone'] %></th>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. No error but don't pass data. I don't know @store_list return type.